# .NET core strip and replace part of URL

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-core, localization, substring

I have localized a website in English and German and I need to display an alternate language in the HTML head section for SEO. For example, if a user is browsing the English version I need to add an alternate link to the German version in view.

```
string currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```

```
@if (currentCulture == "en")
{
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/de/" hreflang="de" />
}
else if (currentCulture == "de")
{
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/en/" hreflang="en" />
}
```

The problem is that I can get `currentUrl` but don't know how to replace language part of URL to be set to opposite language.

When browsing english version currentUrl = https://example.com/en/contact/ so I need to replace `/en/` part with `/de/`

Looking for nicest way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok since you cannot change URL as this is part of the request, what you can do is redirect to URL with correct language. Example by doing something like this:

```
public class LanguageRedirectMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LanguageRedirectMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
      _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        string lang = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

        // Check if the language is supported
        if (lang == "en" || lang == "de")
        {
            // Construct the language-specific URL based on the user's  language preference
            string url = $"/{lang}/{context.Request.Path}{context.Request.QueryString}";

            // Redirect to the language-specific URL
            context.Response.Redirect(url);
            return;
        }

        // Language is not supported, continue processing the request
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

and in your startup.cs :

`app.UseMiddleware<LanguageRedirectMiddleware>();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I found in meantime solution so that I can resolve issue in View. I'm not redirecting to url, just use it in html code

```
// Get the current URL
string currentUrl = Url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl();

// Determine the opposite language code based on the current culture
string oppositeLanguage = currentCulture == "en" ? "de" : "en";

// Replace the language code in the URL
string newUrl = currentUrl.Replace($"/{currentCulture}/", $"/{oppositeLanguage}/");
```